# How to stop receiving packets from pcap.net?

Tags: c#, pcap, pcap.net

I'm looking at pcap.net's ability to intercept packets from various devices.

Starting the process is really straightforward:

```
communicator.ReceivePackets(0, PacketHandler);
```

But after that, the process does not stop. Ever.

How do I forcibly close the packet capture?

Comment: What I did was offload that to a background worker (the whole capture process).

Comment: But you've got to close that eventually.

Comment: I used `PacketCommunicator.ReceivePacket(out Packet);` to receive the packets while the background worker wasn't canceled. and inside the `DoWork()` There was an infinite loop the did just that ( `ReceivePacket()` then process the captured packet).

Comment: In the mean time, I've found following function: Break. Seems to do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, as you've mentioned in the comments, Break() is intended for that.